# randomly draw pixels on a screen with unequal probability distribution

Tags: delphi, random, probability

I want to draw randomly pixels on a screen whereby the probability should not be equally distributed.

Example: Let's say the screen has 1920 x 1080 pixels. On a draw event the probability to be drawn for pixels which lie in a 100 x 100 rectangle at position (500,500) should be 10 times higher then for pixels outside the rectangle.

To achieve this I create first an array which contains the probability. The positions inside the rectangle get a value of 10, all other positions get a value of 1.

```pascal
 for i := 1 to 1920 do
 begin
   for j := 1 to 1080 do
   begin
     FProbability[i, j]:=1;
     if InRange(i, 500, 600) and InRange(j, 500, 600) then
     begin
       FProbability[i, j]:=10;
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

Then I make a list of all pixels:

```pascal
 FPixelList:=TList<TPoint>.Create;
 for i := 1 to 1920 do
 begin
   for j := 1 to 1080 do
   begin
     for k := 1 to FProbabilty[i, j] do
     begin
       FPixelList.Add(TPoint.Create(i,j))
     end;
   end;
 end;
```

The pixel list has now 10 entries for each pixel inside the rectangle and 1 entry for all other pixel positions.

On a draw event I get the pixel position to be drawn by

```pascal
FPixelList[RandomRange(0, FPixelList.Count-1)]
```

This works fine.

However I was wondering if there are other solutions for this problem. My solution uses a lot of memory if the screen sizes become bigger and I can only use integer values for the probability.

Comment: Note that this is essentially a language-agnostic question; the answer would be (essentially) the same in C++, C#, Rust, or x86 assembly. In fact, it is just barely a programming question: it's essentially a pure mathematics question.

Comment: You don't need any memory for this. Suppose the problem was you wanted heads and tails, but tails twice as likely. Then use Random(3) and 0 means heads, 1 or 2 means tails. Extend that concept and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

As David Heffernan has pointed out in the comments, there's no need to use additional storage for this.

Instead we can extend the range of the random selection beyond the size of the image to include `(regionOptions-1)*regionSize` additional values, where `regionOptions` represents the increased likelihood of picking a pixel, in your example this was 10, in a region of size `regionSize`. If the randomly selected value is less than the image size then we use it directly as a position in the image. If it's greater then we perform the calculation to determine the corresponding position in the region of interest.

I'm afraid I'm not familiar with Delphi, so here's some Java code to illustrate.

```java
int imWidth = 1920;
int imHeight = 1000;
int[][] image = new int[imWidth][imHeight];

int regionOptions = 10;
Rectangle region = new Rectangle(500, 500, 100, 100);

int imSize = imWidth * imHeight;

int randomRange = imSize + (regionOptions-1)*region.width*region.height;
        
int max = 0;
Random rand = new Random();
for(int i=0; i<region.width*region.height*1000; i++)
{
    int randPos = rand.nextInt(randomRange);
    
    int x, y;
    if(randPos < imSize)
    {
        x = randPos % imWidth;
        y = randPos / imWidth;
    }
    else
    {
        randPos = (randPos - imSize) / (regionOptions - 1);
        x = region.x + randPos % region.width;
        y = region.x + randPos / region.height;             
    }

    image[x][y] += 1;
    max = Math.max(max, image[x][y]);
}
```

And I used the following code to create a normalized image for the purpose of demonstration:

```java
BufferedImage im = new BufferedImage(imWidth, imHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
for(int i=0; i<imWidth; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<imHeight; j++)
    {
        int level = (int)(255.0*image[i][j]/max);
        im.setRGB(i, j, (level << 16) | (level << 8) | level);
    }
}       
try
{
    ImageIO.write(im, "png", new File("probIm.png"));
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is a clipped region from an image using `regionOptions = 2`. With a value of 10 the normalized pixels are too clustered in the region of interest to show any background.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a different approach an first draw certain number of randomly position pixels across the whole area counting of how many of them were drawn in focused area and how many in normal area.

Then you can simply multiply the number of pixels from normal area by 10 and subtract the number of pixels that were already drawn in the focused are to get the number of pixels that still needs to be drawn in focused are in order to met the desired ration. Once you have this number you just additionally render the needed number of random positioned pixels inside the focused area.

A code to do this will look something like this:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var X,Y,N: Integer;
    Rect: Trect;
    Pt: Tpoint;
    NormalAreaCount, FocusedAreaCount: Integer;
begin
  //Set the rectagle boundaries where pixels needs to be more focused
  Rect.Left := 500;
  Rect.Top := 500;
  Rect.Width := 100;
  Rect.Height := 100;

  //Initialize pixels count variables to 0. Othervise they might end up bein unitialized.
  NormalAreaCount := 0;
  FocusedAreaCount := 0;

  //Use first loop do draw certain number of random pixels across the whole area
  for N := 0 to 200 do
  begin
    X := Random(PaintBox1.Width);
    Y := Random(PaintBox1.Height);
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y] := clBlack;
    Pt.X := X;
    Pt.Y := Y;
    if PtInRect(Rect,Pt) then
    begin
      //if the drawn pixel was in are of focus rectangle increase FocusedAreaCount
      Inc(FocusedAreaCount);
    end
    //else increase NormalAreaCount
    else Inc(NormalAreaCount);
  end;

  //In scond loop draw more random pixels only in focused rectangle area
  //You get the number of pixels taht needs to be drawn by multiplying the number of pixels
  //taht were drawn outsite focused area by 10 and then substract the number of pixels that
  //were already drawn within the focused area
  for N := 0 to (NormalAreaCount*10)-FocusedAreaCount-1 do
  begin
    X := RandomRange(Rect.Left,Rect.Right);
    Y := RandomRange(Rect.Top,Rect.Bottom);
    PaintBox1.Canvas.Pixels[X,Y] := clBlack;
    //Here I increase the FocusedArea count so I can verify the corect number of pixels drawn
    Inc(FocusedAreaCount);
  end;

  //Simply display the number of pixels drawn in focused and normal area for visual verificatiuon
  Form2.Caption := IntToStr(NormalAreaCount)+':'+IntToStr(FocusedAreaCount);
end;
```

Granted this approach does not guarantee you fixed number of total pixels since initial number of pixels that are drawn in normal area is a bit random. Also this code does not guarantee that pixel in focused are does not get drawn over in second loop.